# Getting notifications when the user tries sending an SMS

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, embedded

My application is implemented as a service (running under services.exe).
I am adding a new feature which requires being notified when the user sends an SMS.

I have tried using `IMAPIAdviseSink`, registering with both `IMAPISession` and `IMsgStore`, but I do not get any notifications.

The other options I can see are to create a Short Message Service Provider or to implement the `IFormProviderEx` interface, but I am not sure about the impact this might have on SMS functionality and the user experience.

Is there any way in which my application can reliably get notifications of SMSs being created in the Outbox?

edit: The app is written in native C++. I've looked into RIL and several other APIs, but I can only find information about getting notified of incoming SMSs.

OK, some more information: The same code for registering my `IMAPIAdviseSink` works in a stand alone app. It's only failing to get notifications in the service.

Is there anyway to get notifications in my service? Or do I need a separate process to monitor SMS events and notify my service?

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `IMAPIAdviseSink` from a service.

You need to use it from separate process and notify the service of the events you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

edit: oops, missed that it was users creating the message, not incoming.

Are you targetting windows mobile 5+?

I think what you're looking for is the MessageInterceptor class in the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.MessageInterception Namespace.

Here is a link to some example code:
http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/smartphonesms.html

Peter Foot has included a similar function in His In the Hand libraries, they might allow you to do the same on earlier version of pocket pc.